# Add solution cache file with redis [phalcon, php7.4-redis]

Tags: php, redis, phalcon

$di['cache'] = function () use ($di, $config) {

```
$serializerFactory = new \Phalcon\Storage\SerializerFactory();
$adapterFactory = new \Phalcon\Cache\AdapterFactory($serializerFactory);

$frontend = $adapterFactory->newInstance('apcu', [
    'defaultSerializer' => 'Json',
    'lifetime'          => 7200
]);


$options = array(
    'redis' => $di['redis'],
    'prefix' => $config->session->name.':'
);


$cache = new \Phalcon\Cache\Adapter\Redis($frontend, $options);

return $cache;
```

};

error ==> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Phalcon\Storage\Adapter\Redis::__construct() must be an instance of Phalcon\Storage\SerializerFactory, instance of Phalcon\Cache\Adapter\Apcu given

Answer (score 0):

You should try it that way to implement redis:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Cache\Adapter\Redis;
use Phalcon\Storage\SerializerFactory;

$serializerFactory = new SerializerFactory();

$options = [
    'defaultSerializer' => 'Json',
    'lifetime'          => 7200,
    'host'              => 'xx.xx.xx.xxx',
    'port'              => 6379,
    'index'             => 1,
];

$cache = new Redis($serializerFactory, $options);
return $cache;
```

https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/de-de/cache